# How to run a dependency jar in maven before running the current project

Tags: java, maven, build, build-dependencies

I have a maven project in which I'm trying to get a jar from a remote repository and add it to my local repository. After adding instead of referring its class, I need to run that jar which acts as a input for my current project.

I tried, and there are no build issues, but still it is not triggering to run the dependency.

My pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>secmaven</groupId>
    <artifactId>secmaven</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>secmaven</name>
    <description>secmaven</description>

<build>
<pluginManagement>
<plugins>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.3</version>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>properties</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>

<plugin>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version> 

    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>exec-one</id>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <configuration>
                <includeProjectDependencies>false</includeProjectDependencies>
                <includePluginDependencies>true</includePluginDependencies>
                <executableDependency>
                    <groupId>parent</groupId>
                    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
                </executableDependency>

                <!-- Look up the main class from the manifest inside your dependency's JAR -->
                <mainClass>mainclass</mainClass>
                <arguments>
                </arguments>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
              <goal>java</goal>
           </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
        <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>parent</groupId>
            <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
            <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>C:\....\parent.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
        </dependencies>
</plugin>    
</plugins>
</pluginManagement>
</build>
</project>
```

Comment: Have you add it as a dependency in pom?

Comment: yes i have added, plz check my below pom

Comment: Can you please explain better what you want to do?

Comment: Sorry for not making the requirement clear. For Example: I have two projects say proj1 and proj2. After doing proj1 maven clean deploy, am pushing my proj1 jar to remote repository. This task is done. Coming to my problem : I am able to get the remote jar(proj1) into my proj2. But my question is how to make run my proj1 jar, before running my proj2. Because proj1 data is input to my proj2.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a maven aggregator project pom for that.

Example:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0
                      https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
  <artifactId>my-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.0</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>

  <modules>
    <module>proj1</module>
    <module>proj2</module>
  </modules>
</project>
```

This way proj1 will always run before proj2.

I think is this what you want.

See https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Aggregation for more information.

Comment: what is 'my-parent' artifactid referring here? Will above pom example is the content of my proj2 pom?

Comment: As am running out of time, can Somebody suggest me on this

Comment: Is whatever you want. Your proj2 pom.xml is referred in <module>proj2</module> (proj2 is the name of the directory where you have the proj2 pom). Please refer to maven documentation to understand better the concept.

Comment: Hi, whatever you suggested will work with modules, but in my case i don't have the module. Its jar file. How to work with this